# Invalidating a cached query conditionally in React with useQueryClient hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am quite new to react and am struggling with a subtle problem with data fetching/re-fetching.

We have a data source with its own UI, which lets you create multiple discussion topics and is open to users. These topics can be updated with comments and other activities(deletion of comments/attachments/links) etc from the UI. This data source also exposes endpoints that list all topics currently in the system and the details of user activities on each of them.

Our UI, which is a React app talks to these end points and:

1. lists out the topics.
2. upon clicking on one of the items shows the activity counts on the item.(in a separate panel with two tabs - one for comment and one for other user activities)

I am responsible for number 2 above.

I wrote a custom hook to achieve this goal which is called by the panel and used the useQueryClient to invalidate my query inside the hook, but unfortunately, every time the component(panel) re-renders or I switch between the tabs a new call is made to fetch the count which is deemed unnecessary. Instead we want the call to fetch the counts to go out only when the user clicks on the item and the panel opens up. But I am unable to achieve this without violating the rules of hooks(calling it inside conditionals/ calling it outside of a react component).

```
export const useTopicActivityCounts = (
  topicId: string | undefined,
): ITopicActivityCounts | undefined => {
useQueryClient().invalidateQueries(['TopicActivitytCounts', { topicId }]);
const { data } = useQuery(
    ['TopicActivityCounts', { topicId }],
    () =>
      fetchAsync<IResult<ITopicActivityCount>>(endpointUrl, {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          id,
        },
      }).then(resp => resp?.value),
    {
      enabled: !!topicId,
      staleTime: Infinity,
    },
  );
  return data;
```

this hook is called from here:

```
export const TopicDetails = memo(({ item, setItem }: ITopicDetails): JSX.Element => {
  const counts = useTopicActivityCounts(item?.id);

  const headerContent = (
    <Stack>
      /* page content */
    </Stack>
  );

  const items = [
    /* page content */,
  ];

  const pivotItems = [
    {
      itemKey: 'Tab1',
      headerText: localize('Resx.Comms', { count: counts?.commentsCount ?? '0' }),
    },
    {
      itemKey: 'Tab2',
      headerText: localize('Resx.Activities', { count: counts?.activitiesCount ?? '0' }),
    },
  ];

  return (
    /*
       page content
    */
  );
});
```

I have tried placing it inside an onSuccess inside the hook and that did not work.

Comment: You are invalidating the query so will be refetched again, I see you are using `memo` but if in the parent is not "memoized" since is an object may be a different reference and the memo wont work, but why do you need to invalidate the query just before fetching

Comment: @Woohaik, yes I am not sure about the placement of that invalidate query - I get that currently it is not in the right place. But binding it to an onclick(which opens up the item) or in any other function violates hooks rules. I need to invalidate whenever the user opens the panel.

Comment: if you want to invalidate because the topicId may change there is no need for that react query detects changes in the key and creates a new one, but if want to invalidate for some other reason, call `useQueryClient()` at the beginning and can the method in an if statement  the hook is called normally a call the method `invalidateQueries`  in a conditional

Comment: @Woohaik, sorry I am not able to understand, could you please show me an example using the code posted. Sorry for the trouble.